# Get days as an int from a timespan?

Tags: c#, datetime

Currently I have this:

```
var x = Convert.ToString(dateTimePicker2.Value.Subtract(dateTimePicker1.Value));
int xDays = Convert.ToInt32(x.Substring(0,1));
```

But it's ugly and makes me unhappy on the inside (Also doesn't work for 2 digit day spans, e.g. 15). Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[TimeSpan.Days](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx) returns an integer value representing the days component of the timespan value.

```
 var span = someDate.Subtract(anotherDate);
 int days = span.Days;
```

Comment: timespan makes me happy :)